# Android EditText soft keyboard is not opening with VideoView

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-videoview

I've a `VideoView` and `EditText` on Activity screen.

Then problem is that when screen opens and try to enter the text on `EditText` the soft keyboard didn't open. But when I click on `VideoView` and then click back to `EditText` it opens. Similarly when press back button keyboard become visible.

While it is working fine on some devices

Answer (score 0):

You can add **flags** to your `Activity` which will show the keyboard automatically

```
<activity name="yourpackagename.ActivityName" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"/>
```

In your `Activity` class, you can write below code to show the `keyboard` automatically like this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

For hiding keyboard use:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
```

On `back button press` you can override the `onBackPressed` method in your `Activity` and hide the keyboard so that it is not visible.

Reference doc: [Handle input method visibility - Android](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility)

Hope that helps!